# How do I unmerge a column by its space in R after receiving the column name from a user?

Tags: r

I have the data frame, and one of the column (alpha) has been merged with its space. I want to split that column, and I'm trying to collect the column name from the user before splitting it, however, the code below gives me the output as [,1] [,2]

**code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ID=11:12, alpha=c('a b', 'b c', 'x y'))
library(stringr)
column_name <- readline(prompt="Enter the desired column name: ")
df1<-str_split_fixed(df$column_name, " ", 2)
df1
```

What is the best way to accomplish the necessary outcomes in R? Could someone please assist me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $ is based on columnname. It searches for the column 'column_name' which does not exist.

The code below searches for the string in the variable columnname

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a b', 'b c', 'x y'))
library(stringr)
column_name <- readline(prompt="Enter the desired column name: ")
df1<-str_split_fixed(df[[column_name]], " ", 2)
df1
```

Comment: Yes, it's working, but the column "ID" is missing in the output.